# Icons are not displaying properly in Open and Save dialogs

Tags: windows, icons, windows-server-2008-r2, dialog

My Open and Save dialogs are not showing icons.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have tried resetting the icon cache and restarting Explorer, but nothing works.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: If you log in as a different user does the problem exist for them as well?  You say you tried a cache reset and restarting Explorer, but have you tried an actual reboot yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I have tried